# Ansible XML module cannot find my xml file

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I am trying to read the xml file in my project ( ansible-inventory-check) through ansible xml module. The location of the file on my local machine is:

```
${projectHome}/playbooks/purchaseOrder.xml
```

The file is available in my ubuntu box at:

```
/ansible-inventory-check/playbooks/purchaseOrder.xml
```

But when ansible xml module execute the task of reading the file, It throws an error that it cannot find the file.

```
TASK [Read the xml file] *****************************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [webserver]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "The target XML source '/ansible-inventory-check/playbooks/purchaseOrder.xml' does not exist."}
        to retry, use: --limit @/ansible-inventory-check/playbooks/create-directory.retry
```

The ansible file looks as shown below:

```
- name: Read the xml file
  xml:
    path: /ansible-inventory-check/playbooks/purchaseOrder.xml
    xpath: /PurchaseOrders/PurchaseOrder
    content: text
```

I have already tried changing the path to relative path i.e.

```
path: playbooks/purchaseOrder.xml

path: /playbooks/purchaseOrder.xml

path: ./ansible-inventory-check/playbooks/purchaseOrder.xml
```

but nothing seems to be working. May I know how can I mention the path in yaml file so that ansible can read it.

Comment: I'm having same issue on jenkins. Did you able to manage this ?

Comment: Beware that this error message can be caused by permissions, i.e. a `become: true` might help.

Answer (score 0):

Is the file present is the local or remote server? The xml file should be present in the remote server.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use ansible variable `playbook_dir`?

Something like...

```
- name: Read the xml file
  xml:
    path: "{{ playbook_dir }}/purchaseOrder.xml"
    xpath: /PurchaseOrders/PurchaseOrder
    content: text
```

Ref: [Ansible Special Variables](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/special_variables.html)

Comment: `delegate_to: localhost` can be used to run a task on the control-node.